# How does the expanding of null hypersurface orthogonal geodesic congruence imply a particular result?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics, asymptotics

Sorry that I do not know how to summarize my problem in the title.

First, please go to the website [here](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/270/1340/103) (free access, even though it looks otherwise) to download the paper done by R. Sashs on gravitational waves in an asymptotic flat spacetime. My question is only related to equation (2.5) in page 5.

I might give you some basic info here. For more, please read section 2 Light-like hypersurfaces: local considerations (a) Co-ordinate conventions.

Suppose there is a function $u$ which is essentially the retarded time. It satisfies $g^{ab}\nabla_au\nabla_bu=0$. $\nabla_a$ is the covariant derivative. We can call $k_a=\nabla_au$, so that we have $k_ak^a=0, k^b\nabla_bk^a=0$. So the integral curves of $k^a$ are null geodesics. We further require $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\nabla_ak^a\ne0$, that is, the expansion is nonzero.

In order to build a coordinate system, introduce two more functions, $\theta,\phi$. They follow the conditions:

$k^a\nabla_a\theta=k^a\nabla_a\phi=0$

These conditions simply mean that along the integral curves of $k^a$, these two functions are constant. And these conditions combined with $\rho\ne0$ lead to

$g^{ab}\nabla_a\theta\nabla_b\theta g^{cd}\nabla_c\phi\nabla_d\phi-(g^{ab}\nabla_a\theta\nabla_b\phi)^2\ne0$

But how? I have no idea.